# Trying to take an average of a column with three inner join tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, average

I'm trying to get the average rating for the `rate` column in my `rating` table. After looking up many ways to do this, nothing seems to work for me. It does however work if I don't try to take the average.

Here's my code (Attempt 1):

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
           INNER JOIN mentor ON users.id = mentor.id 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(rating.rate) AS average 
           FROM rating GROUP BY rating.owner) 
           ON mentor.id = rating.owner ORDER BY RAND()";
```

Here's my code (Attempt 2):

```
   $sql = "SELECT users.id, users.username, 
           mentor.industry, mentor.city,  
           AVG(rating.rate) AS average FROM users 
           INNER JOIN mentor ON users.id = mentor.id 
           INNER JOIN rating ON mentor.id = rating.owner
           ORDER BY RAND()";
```

The code after the `SELECT` statement is this:

```
$res = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());               
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $variable= $row['column'];
// more variable naming
   }
}
```

Whenever I re-load my page, it is completely white. The console log says, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Not really sure what to do next. Thanks for any advice, suggestions!

The `owner`column is = mentor.id = users.id

Comment: The 404 message has nothing to do with the SQL. how are you calling this query?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter The code after the select statement is this: `$res = mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());    
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) {
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $variable = $row['column'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems to solve. A problem is that you get a 404. Try to make sure that you request the correct page.

A second problem is your SQL query, which is totally wrong. You try to get record data and aggregate without `group`ing which will throw errors. The second attempt is closer to the correct solution, so let's start from there. This is the attempt:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, 
           mentor.industry, mentor.city,  
           AVG(rating.rate) AS average FROM users 
           INNER JOIN mentor ON users.id = mentor.id 
           INNER JOIN rating ON mentor.id = rating.owner
           ORDER BY RAND()
```

Try to run this query in your RDBMS as it is. You will get an error. You need to `group` the result by user, so user data will become aggregate and since the mentors are giving the ratings, you cannot `select` a mentor, but you can `select` the average `rating`, but then `group` the `users`:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, 
           AVG(rating.rate) AS average FROM users 
           INNER JOIN mentor ON users.id = mentor.id 
           INNER JOIN rating ON mentor.id = rating.owner
           group by users.id, users.username
           ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! I can't thank you enough for your help! I was trying so hard and this was a great learning lesson for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Millica, you are welcome, I am happy I could help you.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I have one more small question for you. I'm trying add a `where` clause before `ORDER BY RAND()`. Do you have any advice on how to do this? This is what I have so far: `WHERE mentor.mentor_enabled='1'`,but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The where clause has to come before the group by syntactically, as the doc says (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html). So you will have select ... from ... inner join ... inner join ... where ... group by ... order by ...

Comment: You're a star!! Thank you! And thank you for the link!!